# GLColorPointer isn't working with glDrawArrays

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I am quite new to OpenGL and am having a bit of trouble with the ColorPointer function in conjunction with DrawArrays ... I can't seem to get the object to render with color .. when I used glColor4f function however this works .. I am thinking it is something to do with how I construct my color FloatBuffer .. however I can't seem to figure this out.

Please have a look at some of my code and let me know what I am doing wrong here ... Also this is my first Stack Over Flow Post (:

```
// function draws the vertices in 3D space
public void draw(GL10 gl){
    // Enable client side access since arrays are store on client side heap
    // and OpenGl is considered server side
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE); // Enable cull face
    gl.glCullFace(GL10.GL_BACK);    // Cull the back face (don't display)
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);

    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, binaryStlParser.getVertices());
    gl.glNormalPointer(GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, binaryStlParser.getNormalVectors());
    gl.glColorPointer(4, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, binaryStlParser.colours);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, (binaryStlParser.getNumOfFacets() * 3));

    //gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SHININESS);
    // disables access given from client side heap for OpenGL
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
}
```

This from another class

```
numOfFacets = ByteBuffer.wrap(numberOfFacets).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).getInt();

        // Allocate memory for the FloatBuffers since we now know the number of Facets
        // we use a ByteBuffer to ensure native ordering .........
        // * 3 for each vertex point in 3D (* 3) space. Size of float is 4 bytes
        vertices = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect((numOfFacets * 3 * 3) * 4)
                        .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();

        // * 3 for each coordinate in vector. Size of float is 4 bytes
        normalVectors = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect((numOfFacets * 3) * 4)
                        .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();

        // * 3 for each vertex point in 4D (* 4) RBGA space. Size of float is 4 bytes
        colours = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect((numOfFacets * 3 * 4) * 4)
                .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();

        for(int i = 0 ; i < numOfFacets*3; i++){
            colours.put(new float[] {0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f});
        }
        colours.position(0);
```

Comment: I don't understand why this keeps getting down posted and why I'm at a negative 2. Constructive criticism would help as well ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out ! Just wanted to post the answer incase it helps someone else (:

Silly mistake ... looks like I was using:

gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

instead of

gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

FloatBuffers are stored on the client side heap, and OpenGL is considered server side I suppose.